# ashx served image renders badly in IIS 8

Tags: .net, ashx, iis-8

I have developed a simple ashx service that pics images from a far-far-away system and renders them in a .net application. Everything works just fine in development that is supposed to be identical to the production environment, hence this seem to be a configuration error.

A page where an image is implemented also returns this message in the log window

> Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html

In production

[image]

In development

[image]

Also, the code and web.config and similar are identical in the environments. I've even copied the entire dev-tree and run it on the development server with the exact same result.

My implementation looks like this

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Write, Script, Execute">
    <remove name="SPImage" />
    <add name="SPImage" verb="GET" path="SPImage.ashx" type="Web.Business.Handlers.SPImage, Web" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

And the handler

```
namespace Web.Business.Handlers
{
    public class SPImage : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            Guid imageGuid;
            if (!Guid.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString["id"], out imageGuid))

            // Get user
            var user = aspnet_MembershipController.Read<aspnet_MembershipListModel>(context.User.Identity.Name);

            // Get requested image
            var image = GalleryListController.ReadImage<IGalleryPicture>(user.ID, imageGuid);
            byte[] file = DownloadProcedureController.Download<byte[]>("gallerier", image.Webimage);

            int width = 270;
            int height = 180;

            // Return image in scaled format
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var settings = new ResizeSettings(string.Format("width={0};height={1};format=jpg;quality={2};mode=crop", width, height, 100)) {};
            // ...process the image
            new ImageResizer.ImageJob(file, stream, settings).Build();

            HttpResponse httpResponse = context.Response;
            httpResponse.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            //httpResponse.CacheControl = "no-cache";
            httpResponse.BufferOutput = false; //Stream the content to the client, no need to cache entire streams in memory...
            httpResponse.BinaryWrite(stream.GetBuffer());
            httpResponse.End();

        }
    }
}
```

Any one recognize this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a fault in ImageReziser where the quality wasn't correctly set. Hence the compressed result. 
Fixed by updating ImageRezising.net